# org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity hibernate4 spring4

Tags: java, spring-4, hibernate-4.x

I am getting the exception 
org.hibernate.MappingException: Unknown entity com.pro.entity.User

I have seen similar posts but almost all of them provides solution to change @Entity annotation to javax.persistence instead of hibernate. Which in my case wasn't useful as I am using correct annotation since the beginning. Here's the code for entity class dao and servlet context.

```
package com.pro.entity;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

@Entity
@Table(name="user")
public class User {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;


    @Id
    @Column(name="userid")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private String id;

    @Column(name="password")
    private String password;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    }
```

Dao class code:

```
public User getUser(String userid)
{

        Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        User user = (User)session.load(User.class, userid);

        return user;

    }
```

context.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/orm 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/orm/spring-orm-4.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-4.0.xsd">

    <beans:bean
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="dataSource"
        class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <beans:property name="url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/pro?useSSL=false" />
        <beans:property name="username" value="user" />
        <beans:property name="password" value="password" />
    </beans:bean>

    <beans:bean id="sessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <beans:property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <beans:property name="hibernateProperties">
            <beans:props>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.dialect">${hibernate.dialect}</beans:prop>
                <beans:prop key="hibernate.show_sql">${hibernate.show_sql}</beans:prop>
            </beans:props>
        </beans:property>
    </beans:bean>


    <beans:bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager">
    <beans:property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"></beans:property>
    </beans:bean>

    <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager"/><tx:annotation-driven/>

    <beans:bean id="persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor" class="org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor"></beans:bean>



    <context:component-scan base-package="com.pro.controller" />

    <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <mvc:annotation-driven />

</beans:beans>
```

Comment: Unless you have a secret hibernate configuration somewhere, hibernate knows nothing about your entity... You haven't specified a package to scan or registered the entities manually. Without that, for hibernate your entity simply doesn't exists, regardless the annotations on it.

Comment: where you put User.java? it it inside  ``com.pro.entity`` package?

Comment: I have actually changed a code before posting here but trust me the project structure is as per the spring specifications.

Answer (score 0):

chnage `<context:component-scan base-package="com.pro.controller" />`
to `<context:component-scan base-package="com.pro" />`
in context.xml

it should work then

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys. I got the solution.... just needed to add following in my context.xml file

```
<beans:property name="annotatedClasses">
            <beans:list>
                <beans:value>com.pro.User</beans:value>
            </beans:list>
        </beans:property>
```